# Komodo IDE running a Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am running a ruby script in Komodo IDE 12.0 . It is a very simple script and I am getting the following error.

```
c:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/lib/byebug/setting.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Byebug::Setting::DEFAULT
c:/ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/lib/byebug/setting.rb:12: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT was here
wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

the script contains on 1 line and it as follows:

```
puts "Hello World"
```

Comment: `puts "Hello World"` will not raise `wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)`, `Hello World`  just 1 argument.Do you have any other code?

Comment: This line is certainly not the error since puts has an arity of -1. `puts` can accept `0..` arguments so it will never raise this error.